# Construct action output from inputs using evaluate

Tags: bixby

I'm trying write an action that accepts a url as input and simply outputs the same url.

I read the documentation on `evaluate` here:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.output.evaluate

That only shows how to do it using a structure and not a primitive like I have.

My action:

```
  description (Fetches External Url)
  type (Constructor)
  collect {
    input (url) {
      type (UrlConcept)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (UrlConcept) {
    evaluate {
      UrlConcept ("#{url}") 
    }
  }
}
```

My Model:

```
text (UrlConcept) {
  description (External Url)
}
```

It never passes the value of url input no matter what formatter I seem to use.

`"#{url}"`, `"#{value(url)}"`, `"${url}"`, etc. all pass the string literal and not the value of url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output would need to be defined as follows:

```
output (UrlConcept) {
  evaluate {
    UrlConcept$expr (url)
  }
}
```